# SSIS FileSystem Task

Tags: ssis, filesystems

I have a filesystem task I would like to move a file from 1 folder to another.
I pick up via SQL task a couple of fields to be put into variables.

I have a SourceUri, for example: http://input.mozilla.com/data/opinions.tsv.bz2
and I Have a desitination: C:\Downloaded

during another SSIS package the file is downloaded to this location
I would like to move the file from: C:\Downloaded\opinions.tsv.bz2 to C:\Archived\opinions.tsv.bz2

I can't seem to customize the task enough where I can give it the variable "http://input.mozilla.com/data/opinions.tsv.bz2" and trim it down to "opinions.tsv.bz2" and build "C:\Downloaded\opinions.tsv.bz2" and then move that to "C:\Archived\"

any help would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0):

In that regard, using a Execute Script task is helpful as you can write C# code and make use of .NET System.IO libraries and string manipulation commands to accomplish your requirement.

Comment: Yeah, I think im going to have to do it programatically, which is fine, I just wish this file Systems task was a little more flexible